# Show shell greeter only on initial login

Tags: bash, session, motd

Is there any way to show a greeter (motd kind of thing) only on initial login, and not when you do `sudo su`?

Here's my current `.bashrc`:

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# ~/.bashrc
#

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return

source ~/.bash_aliases

# My greeter script
greeter
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try to remove the call to `greeter` from your `.bashrc`, and put it in `~/.bash_profile`.

It's only called with login shell.